# How to delete file (image) from filesystem when it is detached from DataObject in SilverStripe admin?

Tags: forms, orm, silverstripe

For Example I have this code

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    private static $has_one = [
        "MyImage" => Image::class,
    ];
    public function getCMSFields(){ 
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', [
            UploadField::create('MyImage');
        ]);
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

When user removes file from MyDataObject in admin

[image: [screen]]

this file still remains in 'files' part of cms, in database and on filesystem, so user need to go to 'files' and remove in manually.

On practice he often forgets to remove file after detaching it from some dataobject and all these files holds a lot of place.

How can SilverStripe automatically remove file from filesystem when users clicks on cross on screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `onAfterDelete()` on your Data Object. There you can delete the file.
(don't forget to call `Parent::onAfterDelete()` in your method)

** UPDATE **

OR if it's only when the user is *editing* not *deleting* your Object, then `onAfterWrite()` is your friend. There you can compare old and new ID of the image, and if is different, delete the Image with the old ID.

Comment: Don't forget to check, if the File is used somewhere else; e.g. if it's a `has_many` to your own DataObject.

Comment: @Ben Did you understood the question correctly? I'm not sure. You are talking about cascade delete, but in question MyDataObject instance needs to stay. Deletes only image from MyDataObject instance.  
  
Now I'm digging into `onAfterWrite()` and `$this->getChangedFields()`

Comment: @FlamyTwista this is not cascadeDelete, rather just a hook where you can delete (or do whatever) your related object when the user removes your dataobject. "in question MyDataObject instance needs to stay" => that's not what you say in your question. "When user removes file from MyDataObject in admin.
this file still remains in 'files' part of cms, in database and on filesystem, so user need to go to 'files' and remove in manually.How can SilverStripe automatically remove file from filesystem when users clicks on cross on screenshot?" sounds like it's exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @FlamyTwista updated response for editing the dataobject

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I've created this extension

```
<?php
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
use SilverStripe\Assets\File;

 class DataObjectRemoveImagesExt extends DataExtension {

     private function killFile($fileId) {
         $fileToRemove = File::get()->byId($fileId);
         if ($fileToRemove) $fileToRemove->delete();
     }

     public function onAfterWrite() {
         $changedFieldsArr = $this->owner->getChangedFields();

         if (!$this->owner->config()->get('kill_on_detach')) return;

         $detachList = $this->owner->config()->get('kill_on_detach');

         foreach ($detachList as $fileFieldName) {
             if (!isset($changedFieldsArr["{$fileFieldName}ID"])) continue;

             $changedFieldValues = $changedFieldsArr["{$fileFieldName}ID"];

             if (
                 (
                     $changedFieldValues['before'] != $changedFieldValues['after']
                     &&
                     $changedFieldValues['before'] != 0
                     &&
                     $changedFieldValues['after'] != 0
                 )
                 ||
                 (
                     $changedFieldValues['after'] == 0
                     &&
                     $changedFieldValues['before'] != 0
                 )
             ){
                 $this->killFile($changedFieldValues['before']);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Usage:
1. Attach to DataObject

```
SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject:
  extensions:
    - DataObjectRemoveImagesExt
```

2. In your custom DataObject child use this property to set files/images to be deleted

   private static $kill_on_detach = [
       'Image',
       'Thumb',
   ];

Solution is not perfect:

- it kills file even if it attached to some another DataObject instance
- it not kills file if user detached file from admin-panel and forgot
  to save DataObject

If somebody wants to propose better decision - welcome.